# Tkinter crashing

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been using tkinter in a python program that I've been working on, and up until today the program was running correctly, but now on running the program without changing any code my computer restarts after responding to the first tkinter window. Running python -m tkinter in the terminal also crashes.

I completely uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda (version 4.7.10)and python (version 3.7.3) and nothing has changed. This is on macOS 10.14.6.

The error message "Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both ... and ... One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined." also displays when the program is run, but I'm not sure if this is a related issue.

Comment: Did you try with different codes?

Comment: Hey @Jamie Bossenbroek, if you add some information the chances you find someone able to help you may raise significantly. For instance, you could add on which OS does it happens, a screenshot of the crash, one piece of the code that cause the crash and so on. Do you agree?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not getting any error messages when the crash happens, my computer just restarts on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS 10.14.6 update causes my MacBook Air to restart when I execute the a Tkinter python script. Worked fine before that. Must be an Apple problem. Even the simplest of scripts causes a catastrophic crash/restart.